# How to disable native fullscreen on IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, fullscreen, video.js

I am using videojs to play a video. Is it possibile to disable the native fullscreen in IOS iphone and use videojs fullscreen?
I tried the playsiline tag but it doesen't work.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Tangential, but I would recommend reconsidering this as a requirement - deviating from a user's established expectations on how these types of components work is setting your users up for a horrible UX.

Answer (score 2):

iPhone still doesn't support the proper full screen API. With the [`preferFullWindow`](https://videojs.com/guides/options/#preferfullwindow) player option (as well as `playsinline`), Video.js will do a "fake" full screen, filling the browser window instead. Not ideal, but the only option if you need to overlay something on top of the video during full screen playback.